# Access elements of vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, vector

I have a little complicated problem. I'll try to explain what I've done.
I have a big class, which has as class-members

```
Mat vidImg
vector<Mat*> *VideoBuffer;
unsigned int currentVideoFrame;
```

I also have a class method

```
void loadVideoInBuffer(int num)
{
    VideoBuffer.clear();
    currentVideoFrame = 0;
    vidDev.open(ListVideos.at(num).absoluteFilePath().toStdString()); // open videofile

    while(true)
    {
        if(vidDev.read(vidImg) == false) // read from file int vidImg object
            break;
        VideoBuffer.push_back(new Mat(vidImg)); // pushback into vector
    }
    ui->tbVideo->setEnabled(true);
}
```

In this I am loading some objects loaded from another file into the Videobuffer vector.
If I try to load it again from this vector in another class-member which I am assigning here:

```
void grabAndProcessFrameVideo() // reload and show loaded inage
{
    if(vidFlag == true)
    {   
        vidImg = Mat(*(VideoBuffer[currentVideoFrame]));  // load from vector
        currentVideoFrame++; // inc index for vector
        imshow("img",vidImg); // show reloaded object in another window
    }
}
```

The Mat Object and imshow function are from the opencv lib but I think that this doesn't really matter. My problem is, that it just shows the last image. If I try to access the buffervector directly in the loading function in this way

```
void EAMViewer::loadVideoInBuffer(int num)
{
    ui->tbVideo->setDisabled(true);
    VideoBuffer.clear();
    currentVideoFrame = 0;
    if(vidDev.open(ListVideos.at(num).absoluteFilePath().toStdString()) == false)
    {
        newLineInText(tr("no Device found"));
        return;
    }
    while(true)
    {
        if(vidDev.read(vidImg) == false)
            break;
        VideoBuffer.push_back(new Mat(vidImg));
        imshow("img",Mat(*(VideoBuffer)[currentVideoFrame]));
        waitKey(30);
        currentVideoFrame++;
    }
    currentVideoFrame = 0;
    ui->tbVideo->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then it shows me it as wanted. So I think that the vector Pointer constellation is problematical if I stay in scope.

My questions are now:
 1. Why the program don't crash while grabbing and processing?
 2. and what can i do, that it prevent deleting?

Thanks in advance,

Inge

Comment: If your grabAndProcessFrameVideo does not show you the good frame, then that's because the currentVideoFrame index is not the right one. And DON'T increment it here (you don't have "pushed back" a new pointer in the vector)

Comment: Hi Manuel,

in which function i have not added a Pointer to the vector?

Inge

Comment: I am surprised the code works at all as VideoBuffer is a pointer so you'd need to do VideoBuffer->push_back... etc. Also the above code doesn't appear to actually create a new vector i.e. there is no VideoBuffer = new vector<Mat*>. In any event you really don't want to be using a pointer to a vector like this

Comment: @Ingeborg in grabAndProcessFrameVideo you increment currentVideoFrame. How do you know that it's then still a valid index? Why increment?

Comment: currentProcessFrame is a classmember in the same class which is intialized in the loading function. Indexing is needed to accessing the single frames from the videobuffer vector.the indexing was the first what i have looked for. I think that it is a scope problem so that it creates a huge leak problem like Ben J already told.

Comment: It's fine to have member variable of type vector<Map*>, as long as you delete each ptr before the .clear(). Fix the source you post. vector<Mat*> *VideoBuffer is not a vector, it's a pointer to a vector. void grabAndProcessFrameVideo() is not a class member, it's a standalone func. Use Mat(*(VideoBuffer[currentVideoFrame])); Anyway, I don't see how leak could lead to showing the last frame when you want the first. Again, if you see the last, it's either because currentVideoFrame is not 0, either because you stored ALL the frame in the first index. Review your usage of currentVideoFrame.

Comment: There's no point writing `Mat(*VideoBuffer[n])`, the result of dereferencing the element is already a `Mat` object, so you can just say `*VideoBuffer[n]`

Answer (score 2):

The reason for why only the last frame is shown is that `Mat` is a reference-counted class. So when you do something like

```
Mat vidImg;
vidDev.read(vidImg);

Mat* a =  new Mat(vidImg);
```

a and vidImg are pointing at the same image. So all your elements in your vector are all pointing to the same (last loaded) image. What you want to do is:

```
Mat a = vidImg.clone();
```

or in your case (removing the pointers too since they shouldn't be there :) )

```
vector<Mat> VideoBuffer;
VideoBuffer.push_back(vidImg.clone());
```

So:

1. Remove all pointers (shouldn't have them raw anyways), since Mat is already a "handle" type class
2. use the `clone()` method to copy the image data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might be because you're dereferencing the vector which as you have it is a pointer to a vector and not a vector, rather than the element that it actually contains.

Maybe try changing

```
vector<Mat*> *VideoBuffer;
```

to

```
vector<Mat*> VideoBuffer;
```

I would also suggest using a vector of smart pointers rather than raw pointers because at the moment your code is leaking memory all over the place. If you stick with the raw pointers you ought to delete each element of the buffer vector before you clear it as clear alone won't deallocate the memory

You'll also need to change

```
imshow("img",Mat(*(VideoBuffer)[currentVideoFrame]));
```

to

```
imshow("img",Mat(*VideoBuffer[currentVideoFrame]));
```

in the lower while loop

Comment: I changed the brackets. It doesn't work either. About the pointer to the vector i have also thought about. I was wondering because other stack variables as class members would deleted also.

the same problem would arise with a pointer to a vector. The memory stucture of the members would be the same.

Maybe the smart pointer is the solution. can you short tell a short summary what that is? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any loop that calls grabAndProcessFrameVideo() so it shows you all the images?

Could it be that it's showing all your images but really fast so you can only see the last one? If so, add a pause like you have in loadVideoInBuffer() (waitKey(30);) and you should see all the images.

Comment: No it won't. grabAndProcessFrameVideo is a slot function which is called after a timer runs down. So that is not the problem. But thanks.